# xdg-open doesn't work when another command's output is piped to it

Tags: bash, pipe

Say I have a unique file somewhere called `file.ext`.
It is indexed by my Ubuntu box, so the command `locate file.ext` correctly gives me the (single) location, say `/usr/local/some/place/file.ext`.

So I thought that this:

```
locate file.ext | xdg-open
```

would open the file with the default application associated with the file type (there is one, that is not the problem), just as if I have entered `xdg-open /usr/local/some/place/file.ext`

Instead, I get the "usage" message coming from `xdg-open`, as if it was called without arguments.

So the question is: did I get something wrong about pipes? Or this some issue with that particular command?

Comment: You are confusing standard input with program arguments. Part of the confusion probably stems from the fact the some programs will process either data read from standard input or data files whose names are given as arguments. `xdg-open` is not one of those programs, though.

Comment: @chepner : Thanks for the tip. Actually, you are correct: as some programs accept both, I made the assumption that I could generalize to all. But after thinking about it, that can't be: from a dev. point of view, arguments are given through `int main(int argc, char ** argv)` which is not related in any way with `stdin`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because you have to pass filename as option, and not data on stdin.
Use xargs for that:

```
locate file.ext | xargs xdg-open
```

or just subshell:

```
xdg-open "$( locate file.ext )"
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested, both work. Now I also better understand the purpose of xargs !